# JD-Eclipse (0.1.3) won't install on Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

When I try to use the "Install New Software..." option in the Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, I receive an error when the installation starts to happen. The details says:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Artifact not found: http://java.decompiler.free.fr/jd-eclipse/update/plugins/jd.ide.eclipse_0.1.3.jar.
http://java.decompiler.free.fr/jd-eclipse/update/plugins/jd.ide.eclipse_0.1.3.jar
Artifact not found: http://java.decompiler.free.fr/jd-eclipse/update/plugins/jd.ide.eclipse.win32.x86_64_0.1.3.jar.
http://java.decompiler.free.fr/jd-eclipse/update/plugins/jd.ide.eclipse.win32.x86_64_0.1.3.jar
```

Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Update site might be dead. Download manually using the mirror site : http://jd.benow.ca/jd-eclipse/downloads/jdeclipse_update_site.zip

Unzip and then use the "Local" option to install the plugin.

Comment: This doesn't work for ubuntu/linux version. I tried to install it on ubuntu 12.04 after restarting eclipse , class files doesn't decompile. Any idea how to get it solved for linux ?